# Borderless window for linux transparency

Tags: c++, linux, x11, xlib

Okay i know for this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1904445/borderless-windows-on-linux) but this method don't work for me because I can't  make 100% transparent "popup" window
with him

This is my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9363491/how-to-make-transparent-window-on-linux)

I search for "good" atom instead of "_MOTIF_WM_HINTS" but i can't find all list of possible
atom names

Comment: Thanks for edit 
How i can edit title

Comment: _MOTIF_WM_HINTS is a hint that your window manager uses to do certain things. If your window manager doesn't support that hint and not all do, then even if you use it, it won't work. Perhaps there is a hint in the NET WM hints. Then a WM that supports those hints (and a lot of them do) should work.

Comment: I think you may be looking for [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9215724/176769).

Comment: Frank Hale :My window manager support _MOTIF_WM_HINTS and when I using him for popup window only it's work perfectly, but when I want popup window with 100% transparency it's fail,window don't have border and it is transparent but not 100%
karlphillip: I use the same answer for trasparent window